# How to add data into nested field via Logstash output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a users index with a nested cars field.
How can I add the mysql result to the nested field of that user.

After some digging to the internet I found this code

```
POST /users/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.cats.add(params.cat)",
    "params": {
      "cat": {
        "colors": 4,
        "name": "Leon",
        "breed": "Persian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I implement it via logstash?
This is my logstash config

```
input {
  jdbc {
    .....
    statement => "select from cars table where...."
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "user_id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
  opensearch {
    ...
    index => "users"
    action => "update"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    script => "ctx._source.cars.add(>>>>>pass the mysql result here<<<<<<<<)"
  }
}
```

Or am I using the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

for me you dont use the good approach.

My advice is to rename fields `colors`, `name` and `breed`

```
input {
  jdbc {
    .....
    statement => "select from cars table where...."
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "user_id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
  }
  mutate {
    rename => {
      "colors" => "[car][colors]"
      "name" => "[car][name]"
      "breed" => "[car][breed]"
    }
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
  opensearch {
    ...
    index => "users"
    action => "update"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```